# Cannot test AsyncTypeahead from react-bootstrap-typeahead with Enzyme

Tags: enzyme, react-bootstrap-typeahead, fetch-mock

I am trying to test **AsyncTypeahead** from **react-bootstrap-typeahead**.

I have a very simple test component :

```
class AsyncTypeahead2 extends Component<Props, State> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: false,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return ( <AsyncTypeahead
            isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
            onSearch={query => {
                this.setState({isLoading: true});
                fetch("http://www.myHTTPenpoint.com")
                    .then(resp => resp.json())
                    .then(json => this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        options: json.items,
                    }));
            }}
            options={this.state.options}
            labelKey={option => `${option.stateName}`}
        /> )
    }
}

const url = "http://www.myHTTPenpoint.com"
fetchMock
    .reset()
    .get(
        url,
        {
            items: [
                {id:1, stateName:"Alaska"},
                {id:2, stateName:"Alabama"}
            ]
        },
    );
```

(Note that the URL is mocked to return two elements)

When I run this in my storybook it looks fine :

[image]

But if I want to test it (with Enzyme) it does not recognise the **< li >** items that pop up.

```
    let Compoment =
        <div>Basic AsyncTypeahead Example
            <AsyncTypeahead2/>
        </div>

    const wrapper = mount(Compoment);
    let json = wrapper.html();


    let sel = wrapper.find(".rbt-input-main").at(0)

    sel.simulate('click');
    sel.simulate('change', { target: { value: "al" } });

    expect(wrapper.find(".rbt-input-main").at(0).getElement().props.value).toBe("al")

    expect(wrapper.find(".dropdown-item").length).toBe(2) //but get just 1 element "Type to Search..."
```

Instead of finding two "dropdown-item" items there is just one item with the text "Type to Search...".

Is the AynchTypeahead not updating the DOM correctly with respect to Enzyme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact solution to my problem is in the following code (copy and paste into a JS file to see it work).

Things to note :

- I needed to use the **waitUntil** function from the **async-wait-until** library. fetch-mock on its own does not provide the functionality to test async code.
- I needed to add an ugly hack at global.document.createRange because of some tooltip issue with react-bootstrap-typeahead and jest.
- use waitUntil to wait on changes on the internal state of the component
- It is very important to call wrapper.update() to update the DOM afterwards.

..

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import waitUntil from 'async-wait-until';

import {mount} from "enzyme";
import fetchMock from "fetch-mock";
import {AsyncTypeahead} from "react-bootstrap-typeahead";


describe('Autocomplete Tests ', () => {

    test(' Asynch AutocompleteInput  ', async () => {

        class AsyncTypeaheadExample extends Component<Props, State> {

            constructor(props: Props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    isLoading: false,
                    finished: false
                };
            }

            render() {
                return (<AsyncTypeahead
                    isLoading={this.state.isLoading}
                    onSearch={query => {
                        this.setState({isLoading: true});
                        fetch("http://www.myHTTPenpoint.com")
                            .then(resp => resp.json())
                            .then(json => this.setState({
                                isLoading: false,
                                options: json.items,
                                finished: true
                            }));
                    }}
                    options={this.state.options}
                    labelKey={option => `${option.stateName}`}
                />)
            }
        }

        const url = "http://www.myHTTPenpoint.com"
        fetchMock
            .reset()
            .get(
                url,
                {
                    items: [
                        {id: 1, stateName: "Alaska"},
                        {id: 2, stateName: "Alabama"}
                    ]
                },
            );

        let Compoment =
            <AsyncTypeaheadExample/>


        // ugly hacky patch to fix some tooltip bug
        // https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15726
        global.document.createRange = () => ({
            setStart: () => {
            },
            setEnd: () => {
            },
            commonAncestorContainer: {
                nodeName: 'BODY',
                ownerDocument: document,
            },
        });

        let wrapper = mount(Compoment);

        let sel = wrapper.find(".rbt-input-main").at(0)

        sel.simulate('click');
        sel.simulate('change', {target: {value: "al"}});
        expect(wrapper.find(".rbt-input-main").at(0).getElement().props.value).toBe("al")




        //now the async stuff is happening ...

        await waitUntil(() => {
            return wrapper.state().finished === true;
        }, 3000); //wait about 3 seconds

        wrapper.update() //need to update the DOM!

        expect(wrapper.find(".dropdown-item").length).toBe(2) //but get just 1 element "Type to Search..."
    })
});
```

UPDATE

---

I can also compare on wrapper items rather than doing a direct comparison on the state :

```
//now the async stuff is happening ...
await waitUntil(() => {
    wrapper.update() //need to update the DOM!

    return wrapper.find(".dropdown-item").length > 1
}, 3000); //wait about 3 seconds
```

This is probably better because it means i dont need to know about the component internals.

Answer (score 1):

[`<AsyncTypeahead>`](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#asynchronous-searching) is **asynchronous**. On the other hand `simulate()` is **synchronous**. So at the time you get to `expect()` `AsyncTypeahead` not even started to populate the dropdown with `<li>` elements. You need to wait for it.

It's not specified, but it looks like you are using `fetch-mock` package.
There is the [`flush`](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#api-lifecycleflush) function which

> Returns a Promise that resolves once all fetches handled by fetch-mock have resolved

So this:

```js
...

sel.simulate('click');
sel.simulate('change', { target: { value: "al" } });

await fetchMock.flush() // !!!

expect(wrapper.find(".rbt-input-main").at(0).getElement().props.value).toBe("al")
expect(wrapper.find(".dropdown-item").length).toBe(2)
```

should work.

...But probably it won't. Because

```js
fetchMock.mock(...)
fetch(...)
await fetchMock.flush()
```

does work, but

```js
fetchMock.mock(...)
setTimeout(() => fetch(...), 0)
await fetchMock.flush()
```

does not. `await fetchMock.flush()` returns right away if there was no call of `fetch`. And probably there won't be. Because `<AsyncTypeahead>` debounces.

(By the way, you can also try to mock `fetch` on a per-test basis. Just in case.)

So I see two options:

1. Use something else instead of `fetch-mock` package. Where you can resolve your own `Promises` on mocked requests completion.
2. https://tech.travelaudience.com/how-to-test-asynchronous-data-fetching-on-a-react-component-ff2ee7433d71

   ```js
   import waitUntil from 'async-wait-until';
   ...
   test("test name", async () => {
       let Compoment = <AsyncTypeahead2/>
       ...
       await waitUntil(() => wrapper.state().isLoading === false);
       // or even
       // await waitUntil(() => wrapper.find(".dropdown-item").length === 2, timeout);
       expect(...)
   })
   ```

   This options if not pretty. But maybe it's your only option - there is not only the `fetch-mock` you should worry about. `setState` also asynchronous... and it looks like there is no pretty way to check when it's done updating the state and the `DOM` without changing the real code (which is quite undesirable).

Comment: yes you are right. I am using fetch-mock. I did try how you suggested but I am still not having any luck... trying a few other things but the async keyword seems to be the key

Comment: I think I need to do some kind of await on the fetch defined in the onSearch callback

Comment: Yes. But the sad thing is that this would require changing your real code for the sake of tests.

Comment: yeah... i was thinking the same. :(

Comment: Maybe another mock lib? https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock#functions It looks like with it you can defined your own promises to wait for.

Comment: Played a little with `fetch-mock` and `AsyncTypeahead`. Updated the answer. There is a change in the `flush` call. Initially I was wrong: `await promise` must be changed to `await fetchMock.flush()` but... read on :)

Comment: alright thanks very much for your help :) I'll leave the bounty up until the end incase someone else comes up with an answer. I'll let you know if i find something

Comment: thanks for your help :) I managed to fix this but you got me on the right track. I will post my answer